# telnet connection to apc with python script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to telnet to apc machine, but seeing issue with pexpect.
I do not have ssh on the machine, so need to use telnet only.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import pexpect
import sys
import time
apc_ip = "x.x.x.x"
user   = "x"
passwd = "y"
outlet  = "z"
switch = pexpect.spawn('telnet x.x.x.x')
switch.logfile = sys.stdout
switch.timeout = 10
switch.expect('User Name : ')
switch.send('x' + '\r\n')
switch.expect('Password  : ')
switch.sendline('y' + '\r\n')
switch.expect('apc>')
```

Here is what I see when I run it:

```
[~]$ python 1.py
Trying x.x.x.x...
Connected to x.x.x.x.
Escape character is '^]'.

User Name : x
apc
Password  : x

****
User Name :
```

Do I need to flush the output somewhere? Each time I run, I hit different issues, tried '\r', '\n' everything.

Here is the manual output:

```
[ops@cn68xx ~]$ telnet x.x.x.x
Trying x.x.x.x...
Connected to x.x.x.x.
Escape character is '^]'.

User Name : x
Password  : ***

Schneider Electric                      Network Management Card AOS      v6.4.4
(c) Copyright 2016 All Rights Reserved  RPDU 2g APP                      v6.4.4
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name      : apcFABE5B                                 Date : 08/03/2017
Contact   : Unknown                                   Time : 12:05:27
Location  : Unknown                                   User : Super User
Up Time   : 1 Day 1 Hour 19 Minutes                   Stat : P+ N4+ N6+ A+


Type ? for command listing
Use tcpip command for IP address(-i), subnet(-s), and gateway(-g)

apc>
```

Can someone please help me resolving this issue?

Comment: Have you tried the builtin [`telnet` library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html)?

Comment: Yes, I did try. but dint work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I founded this problem of APC interpreter too. Problem is in /r symbol. Use something like this (it works):

```
t = pexpect.spawn('telnet 10.0.0.2')
t.expect('User Name : ')
t.send('apc\r')
t.expect('Password  : ')
t.send('apc\r')
time.sleep(1)
t.expect('apc>')
t.send('uio -st 1\r')
t.expect('apc>')
t.sendline('exit')
time.sleep(2)
print t.before
```